# Webmin FTP User - Create user to view another users folder

Tags: ftp, webmin

So I have a server with Webmin installed and I've succesfully managed to create a user with an ftp group and setup the account in such a way that once they ftp into the site, they can only view their ftp folder...all good.

However I just wondered if there is a way to setup another user, but allow them to access the previous users folder via FTP?

There is an option to choose the home directory when creating the user, but it doesn't list the '/user' folder which is I presume the virtual folder for each an every user that gets created by Webmin (incidentally where exactly on the server do all the files get uploaded to?).

So user_1 has an FTP group and when they login using their ftp details, they see their folder.

user_2 needs to be added so they can ftp into exactly the same folder as user_1.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Let's assume you have something like:*

- `/shared`
- `/home/steve`
- `/home/simon`

And you would like for both users Steve and Simon to be able to access `/shared` then the simplest way would be to create the folder and [then assign it an FTP group](https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Users_and_Groups) allowing both users write/read access as required.

Then to have `/shared` visible when either Simon or Steve login to the FTP, you simply [create a symbolic link](https://support.eapps.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/235/56/webmin-control-panel-eapps---using-the-file-manager#creating_symbolic_links) which basically adds a shortcut in `/home/simon/shared`. If you want your server to do this automatically when adding a new user then you need to code a script or use [custom commands](https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Custom_Commands).

Now with all this said... ideally, you should opt to use SFTP rather than FTP, its more secure (SSH keys) and has better functionality, you also get to disable the FTP service entirely.

Comment: Hi Simon, I greatly appreciate your response, and I am indeed using SFTP to connect in the end (forgot to clarify that).

Also may I also clarify my request? Here is an image (hopefully) of what my users look like in Webmin 

https://ibb.co/hBaBcK

So really I just want to know if its feasible for user_1 to be able to view user_2's files? Bare in mind see how each of their home directories are simply '/user' which seems like a virtual folder as I can't find this on the server anywhere.

Regards

Comment: Yes, you can use chmod e.g 777 on the folder which will give other users access but you will still need to create the sym link as mentioned, or add user2 to the group user1.